# Pandas/Python - Updating dataframes based on value match

Tags: python, pandas

I want to update the `mergeAllGB.Intensity` columns `NaN` values with values from another dataframe where ID, weekday and hour are matching. I'm trying:

```
mergeAllGB.Intensity[mergeAllGB.Intensity.isnull()] = precip_hourly[precip_hourly.SId == mergeAllGB.SId & precip_hourly.Hour == mergeAllGB.Hour & precip_hourly.Weekday == mergeAllGB.Weekday].Intensity
```

However, this returns `ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare`. How could I do this?

Minimal example:

```
Inputs:
_______
mergeAllGB
SId  Hour Weekday Intensity
1    12   5       NaN
2    5    6       3

precip_hourly
SId  Hour Weekday Intensity
1    12   5       2

Desired output:
________
mergeAllGB
SId  Hour Weekday Intensity
1    12   5       2
2    5    6       3
```

Comment: I'm trying to make this work using `set_value`. But I would assume I'd get the same error/incorrect result because of non-matching length. But maybe someone will see it and it will spark an idea: `df = mergeALLGB.set_value(mergeAllGB['Intensity'].isnull(), 'Intensity', precip_hourly['Intensity'])`

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR this will (hopefully) work:

```
# Set the index to compare by
df = mergeAllGB.set_index(["SId", "Hour", "Weekday"])
fill_df = precip_hourly.set_index(["SId", "Hour", "Weekday"])

# Fill the nulls with the relevant values of intensity
df["Intensity"] = df.Intensity.fillna(fill_df.Intensity)
# Cancel the special indexes
mergeAllGB = df.reset_index()
```

Alternatively, the line before the last could be

```
df.loc[df.Intensity.isnull(), "Intensity"] = fill_df.Intensity
```

---

Assignment and comparison in `pandas` are done by index (which isn't shown in your example).

In the example, running `precip_hourly.SId == mergeAllGB.SId` results in `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`. This is because we try to compare the two columns by value, but `precip_hourly` doesn't have a row with index `1` (default indexing starts at 0), so the comparison fails.

Even if we assume the comparison succeeded, the assignment stage is problematic. 
Pandas tries to assign according to the index - but this doesn't have the intended meaning.

Luckily, we can use it for our own benefit - by setting the index to be `["SId", "Hour", "Weekday"]`, any comparison and assignments will be done with relation to this index, so running `df.Intensity= fill_df.Intensity` will assign to `df.Intensity` the values in `fill_df.Intensity` wherever the index match, that is, wherever they have the same `["SId", "Hour", "Weekday"]`.

In order to assign only to the places where the `Intensity` is `NA`, we need to filter first (or use `fillna`). Note that filter by `df.Intensity[df.Intensity.isnull()]` will work, but assignment to it will probably fail if you have several values with the same (`SId`, `Hour`, `Weekday`) values.